# How do I ignore invalid rows in U-SQL EXTRACT that don't fit schema?

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to extract some data from a CSV file using the following U-SQL EXTRACT statement:

```
EXTRACT SessionId   string,
        Latitude    double,
        Longitude   double,
        Timestamp   int
FROM "wasb://sessions@myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/"
USING Extractors.Csv();
```

But my job is failing halfway through because there is a row that doesn't fit this schema (common in huge datasets) because it has the wrong number of columns.  How do I avoid that this fails the entire extract?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the slient:true parameter to Extractors.Csv() ala:

```
EXTRACT SessionId   string,
        Latitude    double,
        Longitude   double,
        Timestamp   int
FROM "wasb://sessions@myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/"
USING Extractors.Csv(silent:true);
```

Answer (score 7):

Note that the silent flag will do the following:

1. Ignore rows that have mismatched column counts
2. replace invalid values with null **if** the column type is nullable.

It will **still error** if:

1. the value cannot be cast to the expected not-nullable type.
2. there is an invalid character for the specified encoding.

Comment: Is there a mechanism you can use to ignore rows with the "still error" conditions above?

Comment: You would have to write your own custom extractor. If you have specific scenarios, feel free to also add a feature request on the built-in extractors at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.